# How can I read Total bytes per sector value using PowerShell or Cmd?

Tags: powershell, sector

I heard that the disk sector's size is not 512 bytes, but 571 bytes.

```
Total bytes per sector: 571 bytes (59 B for Header + 512 B for Data)
Data bytes per sector: 512 bytes
```

And I want to query using PowerShell or Cmd Prompt to view that number '571' .

P.S. Failed with `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo [Drive Letter]`

[image]

Comment: Please clarify how you obtained the sample output in your question, given that it is _not_ part of the output from `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo [Drive Letter]`

Comment: where do you hear that a sector is 571 bytes? The header may be there but it's an internal structure of the disk to self-manage the space, how can the OS know that?

Comment: @mklement0 I added!

Comment: @phuclv Through googling, found that 59 bytes of header structure existed. So even if there is a header, there is no way to access it in the OS? I'd appreciate it if you could explain it in detail.

Comment: as said, it's an internal structure of the disk, so there's no way for the outside world like the OS to know this. It may not even be the same for every disk. Probably some low-level tool for that specific disk can read this but not a general shell like cmd or PowerShell

Comment: Cmd: WMIC DiskDrive

Comment: As of win10, you should be able to use: `fsutil fsinfo sectorInfo C:`. `sectorInfo` was added for this purpose

Comment: @AbrahamZinala that's absolutely wrong. Did you even try to run that? It'll never give you that internal sector size because that's never exposed to the OS

Comment: @Darin that won't work. `wmic` doesn't know the drive's internal sector size and can't give you the 571 value. Moreover `wmic` has  been deprecated

Comment: @phuclv Thank you for your all these help. Now I understand why I can't see those 571 bytes through shell!!